# Drag and drop strage behaviour

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a very strange problem, and I hope someone can help me. In short, I have decided not to allow drag and drop between left and right panels (horizontally; draggable, droppable) but only up and down within the same column (vertically; sortable). Instead I have decided to have an icon that moves the one block from right to left or vice versa. See screenshot attached.

What happens is that the vertical sortable is working, and the horizontal "move" function works THE FIRST TIME for each block, but than not again until I close and re-open the dialog.[image: This screenshot shows the effect of what I intend to do.]

Here is the source code:

```
<?php

    $out = '
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function serializeList(container)
            {
                var str = "";
                var els = $("#" + container).find("li");
                for (var i = 0; i < els.length; ++i)
                {
                    var el = els[i];
                    var p = el.id.lastIndexOf("_");
                    var getIdNumber = el.id.split("_");
                    if (p != -1)
                    {
                        str = str + "/" + getIdNumber[1];
                    }
                }
                return str;
            }
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(function() {
                    $("#blocks-left > ul").sortable({ opacity: 0.8, cursor: "move", update: function() {
                        var order = "/left" + serializeList("blocks-left > ul");
                        $.post("' . base_url() . 'content/admin/reorder_blocks_left/' . $page . '" + order, {' . $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() . ' : "' . $this->security->get_csrf_hash() . '"});
                    }});
                    $("#blocks-right > ul").sortable({ opacity: 0.8, cursor: "move", update: function() {
                        var order = "/right" + serializeList("blocks-right > ul");
                        $.post("' . base_url() . 'content/admin/reorder_blocks_right/' . $page . '" + order, {' . $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() . ' : "' . $this->security->get_csrf_hash() . '"});
                    }});
                    $("#content > ul").sortable({ opacity: 0.8, cursor: "move", update: function() {
                        var order = serializeList("content > ul");
                        $.post("' . base_url() . 'content/admin/reorder_elements/' . $page . '" + order, {' . $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() . ' : "' . $this->security->get_csrf_hash() . '"});
                    }});
                    $("a[id^=\"move-left\"]").click(function() {
                        alert("Clicked a move to left icon!");
                        var theID = $(this).parent().attr("id");
                        var theIDNumber = theID.split("_");
                        var theContent = $(this).parent().attr("data-content");
                        var theText = $(this).parent().attr("data-move-text");
                        $("#blocks-left > ul").append("<li data-move-text=\"Click to move right\" data-content=\"" + theContent + "\" style=\"padding: 5px; margin: 5px 0; background-color: #CCEEFF; color: #444444; border: 1px solid #A7C1CE;\" id=\"" + theID + "\"><a id=\"move-right-" + theIDNumber[1] + "\" href=\"#\"><img style=\"width: 16px; height: 16px; margin-right: 16px;\" src=\"' . base_url() . 'assets/images/reorder.png\" alt=\"Click to move right\" title=\"Click to move right\" /></a>" + theContent + "</li>");
                        $(this).parent().remove();
                        $.post("' . base_url() . 'content/admin/move_block_left/' . $page . '/" + theIDNumber[1], {' . $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() . ' : "' . $this->security->get_csrf_hash() . '", rand : "rid-' . mt_rand(0, 19999999) . '" });
                    });
                    $("a[id^=\"move-right\"]").click(function() {
                        alert("Clicked a move to right icon!");
                        var theID = $(this).parent().attr("id");
                        var theIDNumber = theID.split("_");
                        var theContent = $(this).parent().attr("data-content");
                        var theText = $(this).parent().attr("data-move-text");
                        $("#blocks-right > ul").append("<li data-move-text=\"Click to move left\" data-content=\"" + theContent + "\" style=\"padding: 5px; margin: 5px 0; background-color: #CCEEFF; color: #444444; border: 1px solid #A7C1CE;\" id=\"" + theID + "\"><a id=\"move-left-" + theIDNumber[1] + "\" href=\"#\"><img style=\"width: 16px; height: 16px; margin-right: 16px;\" src=\"' . base_url() . 'assets/images/reorder.png\" alt=\"Click to move left\" title=\"Click to move left\" /></a>" + theContent + "</li>");
                        $(this).parent().remove();
                        $.post("' . base_url() . 'content/admin/move_block_right/' . $page . '/" + theIDNumber[1], {' . $this->security->get_csrf_token_name() . ' : "' . $this->security->get_csrf_hash() . '", rand : "rid-' . mt_rand(0, 19999999) . '" });
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <h1>Page layout</h1>
                <p>To change the layout of a page, please click on the block or content piece, hold the mouse button, and drag it down to the position you want it in. When done, simply close the dialog.</p>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span3">
                        <div id="blocks-left" style="padding: 5px;">
                            <ul style="border: 1px dashed #cccccc; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 10px 15px;">
    ';
    if (isset($left_blocks) && is_array($left_blocks) && !empty($left_blocks))
    {
        foreach ($left_blocks as $key => $val)
        {
            $out .= '<li data-move-text="Click to move right" data-content="' . $val['title'] . '" style="padding: 5px; margin: 5px 0; background-color: #CCEEFF; color: #444444; border: 1px solid #A7C1CE;" id="block_' . $val['block_id'] . '"><a id="move-right-' . $val['block_id'] . '" href="#"><img style="width: 16px; height: 16px; margin-right: 16px;" src="' . base_url() . 'assets/images/reorder.png" alt="Click to move right" title="Click to move right" /></a>' . $val['title'] . '</li>';
        }
    }
    $out .= '
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span6">
                        <div id="content" style="padding: 5px;">
                            <ul style="border: 1px dashed #cccccc; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 10px 15px;">
    ';
    if (isset($content) && is_array($content) && !empty($content))
    {
        foreach ($content as $key => $val)
        {
            $out .= '<li style="padding: 5px; margin: 5px 0; background-color: #CCEEFF; color: #444444; border: 1px solid #A7C1CE;" id="arrayorder_' . $val['content_id'] . '">' . $val['title'] . '</li>';
        }
    }
    $out .= '
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span3">
                        <div id="blocks-right" style="padding: 5px;">
                            <ul style="border: 1px dashed #cccccc; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 10px 15px;">
    ';
    if (isset($right_blocks) && is_array($right_blocks) && !empty($right_blocks))
    {
        foreach ($right_blocks as $key => $val)
        {
            $out .= '<li data-move-text="Click to move left" data-content="' . $val['title'] . '" style="padding: 5px; margin: 5px 0; background-color: #CCEEFF; color: #444444; border: 1px solid #A7C1CE;" id="block_' . $val['block_id'] . '"><a id="move-left-' . $val['block_id'] . '" href="#"><img style="width: 16px; height: 16px; margin-right: 16px;" src="' . base_url() . 'assets/images/reorder.png" alt="Click to move left" title="Click to move left" /></a>' . $val['title'] . '</li>';
        }
    }
    $out .= '
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    ';
    echo $out;

?>
```

When looking at the generated source below, you can see that there is no obvious reason why I will be able to move the `<li>`s with IDs `block_1` and `block_2`, but the `<li>` with ID `block_3` will not move the second time around. Bizarre...

[image: Generated source - <code><li id="block_e...</code> used to be on the rigtht-hand-side in this case.]

From the above code you may assume that all PHP variables are populated correctly.

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No responses here, and deadline was running too close, so I did not solve this, but did rewrote the entire code section, and have a workable alternative now.